# A lot of logging output about _solClient_context_registerForFdEvents

Tags: solace

all

When doing some bridge-type work with Solace, I notice a huge increase in the amount of log output like:

Sdk _solClient_context_registerForFdEvents, fd 2436, events 2, callback 000000001001EC10, user data 0000000008B78960 for session '(c1,s1)_jsqual2'

Sdk _solClient_context_unregisterForFdEvents, fd 2436, events 2 for session '(c1,s1)_jsqual2'

Sdk _solClient_context_registerForFdEvents, fd 2436, events 2, callback 000000001001EC10, user data 0000000008B78960 for session '(c1,s1)_jsqual2'

Sdk _solClient_context_unregisterForFdEvents, fd 2436, events 2 for session '(c1,s1)_jsqual2'

Sdk _solClient_context_registerForFdEvents, fd 2436, events 2, callback 000000001001EC10, user data 0000000008B78960 for session '(c1,s1)_jsqual2'

Sdk _solClient_context_unregisterForFdEvents, fd 2436, events 2 for session '(c1,s1)_jsqual2'

So there is a lot of registering and unregistering something :)

I use separate contexts and sessions for subscribing and publishing and send outgoing messages to >1 sessions directly from within the Solace message callback handler on the subscriber session.

Any idea what these might be and what they indicate? The amount of logging is high and it's at INFO level so not too easy to filter out.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These log entries are generated when the API registers/unregisters a file descriptor event. These can be either read or write events.

In general, read events are only registered while connecting to Solace. Write events are generated when the API tries to write data, but can not write all bytes in one attempt. Usually in this case, the SOLCLIENT_STATS_TX_SOCKET_FULL statistic will increment.

It is normal to see these logs generated at INFO level, they do not indicate anything unusual.